# Job messages gone after merge

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, merge-accounts, private-messaging

I accidentally made a new account recently when I applied for a job.
I merged the accounts now, but the Messages from the new account dissapeared.
Is there a way to restore them?

Answer (score 2):

[Contact our support team](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and they'll be happy to look into this for you.

Make sure to select "I need help with Stack Overflow Jobs" from the dropdown.